# Store 2D array row in parallel array

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner to C++, in my homework i have to save a row from a 2D array based on the inputted username and password. The saved row is to be a reference as to where the user info can be found in the 2D array. I haven't been able to figure out how to save the specific row to an integer. The whole code is displayed and the function to preform the task is called validateUser.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void showAll(string theAccounts[5][7]);
void sortInput(string theAccounts[5][7]);
bool validateUser(string theAccounts[5][7], string username, string password,     int &saveRow);
bool readFile(string theAccounts[5][7]);

int main()
{
//Declare Necessary Variables and 2D array to store data from input file.
string username;
string password;
string accountData[5][7] = { " " };
bool userGood;
bool fileGood;

    //Call the readFile function and capture the returned value.
fileGood = readFile(accountData);

//Test if file was successfully read, if so continue with program else exit with error message
if (fileGood == false)
{
    cout << "Error occurred...File Unread...Program Exiting" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "\nFile Read Successfully...\n\n" << endl;

    //Ask user to Enter User Name or Zero to Exit
    cout << "Enter the following information or 0 to Exit...\n";
    cout << "Please Enter Your User Name > ";

    //Read in User Name     
    //If User Name read in is “zero” Exit program.
    cin >> username;
    if (username == "0")
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //Ask the user to Enter Their Password or Zero to Exit
    cout << "Please Enter Your User Password > ";

    //Read in User Password
    //If User Password read in is “zero” Exit program
    cin >> password;
    if (password == "0")
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //Call the Validate User function and capture the returned value

    //If returned value from the Validate User function is TRUE continue program to check access code if U or A
    //If U – code appropriately
    //If A – code appropriately

    //Else if returned value Not Valid from the Validate User function, FALSE, output message username and password invalid

}
return 0;
}

void showAll(string theAccounts[5][7])
{
const int Rows = 5;
const int Columns = 7;

ifstream accountFile;
accountFile.open("AccountData.txt");

if (accountFile.is_open())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Columns; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(8) << theAccounts[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
accountFile.close();
}
void sortInput(string theAccounts[5][7])
{

}

bool validateUser(string theAccounts[5][7], string username, string password, int &saveRow)
{
bool passed = false;
//test for username and password match whats stored in theAccounts
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (username == theAccounts[i][0] && password == theAccounts[i][3])
    {
        saveRow = theAccounts[i];
    }
}

return passed;
}

bool readFile(string theAccounts[5][7])
{
bool fileRead;
const int Height = 5;
const int Width = 7;

ifstream inputFile; //an ifstream object – input file stream object
inputFile.open("AccountData.txt"); // the open member function opens the text file and links it with
                                   // inputFile to read data from the AccountData.txt file

//input validation to see if file opened
//if opened, read strings into theAccounts array - reset fileRead to true
if (inputFile.is_open())
{
    fileRead = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Width; j++)
        {
            inputFile >> theAccounts[i][j];
        }
    }
}
else
{
    fileRead = false;
}

inputFile.close();
return fileRead;
}
```

The .txt file contains:

bham@gnet.com  Blake  Ham       squid62     1987    U   Teacher

jdark@att.net   Jim     Dark        gymrat32    1985    A   Master

hgreen@lakes.net    Hannah  Green   flower22    2007    U   Apprentice

tsmith@dna.com  Tom     Smith   tuna20      2000    U   Teacher

jarrow@pnet.com James   Arrow   ahoy10      2005    U   Apprentice

Comment: look up `std::map<Key, Value>`. It is a container where `Keys` are all unique and can be of any type you desire. Also `Values` can be any type you want but can be duplicated. So,  image it as `std::map<Deepblue, information>` is an element, another element would be `std::map<FirstStep, information>` and so on. No two identical keys can be found.

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't been able to figure out how to save the specific row to an
>   integer

In OP function, the specific row is simply `i`, so all we have to do is to assign it to the variable passed by reference, `saveRow` and return.

I will not comment the general design of this program as I don't know how much of it is part of the assignment, so I'll use the same interface and data structures OP used:

```
bool validateUser(string theAccounts[5][7], string username, string password, int &saveRow)
{
    //test for username and password match whats stored in theAccounts
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (username == theAccounts[i][0] && password == theAccounts[i][3])
        {
            // match found, "save" the right row and return
            saveRow = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    // there's no match
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For cleaner and easier approach, You should use a combination of `std::map` and `std::vector`. `std::map<Key, Value>` is a container where `Keys` are all unique and can be of any type you desire. Also `Values` can be any type you want but can be duplicated. So, imagine it as `std::map<Deepblue, information>` is an element, another element would be `std::map<FirstStep, information>` and so on. No two identical keys can be found. Therefore, the `Key` will be a `string` and the `Information` is going to be a `vector<string>` container of strings.

The below code works and it populates all your data from the input file to the map. Follow the comments and you should see how it works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>



int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> MyMap; // map that has a string key and a vector of strings as information

    std::ifstream InFile; // to read from a text file

    InFile.open("C:\\....\\input.txt");

    if (InFile.fail()) // terminate if failed
    {
        std::cout << "File did not open correctly!";
        return 0;
    }

    std::string OneLine;
    std::vector<std::string> MyVector;
    std::string MyKey;
    std::vector<std::string> MyValue;

    while(std::getline(InFile, OneLine)) // while "reading a whole line" is valid
    {
        //split the whole line on whitespaces and convert it to a vector of strings
        std::stringstream ss(OneLine); 
        std::string item;
        while (getline(ss, item, ' ')) 
            MyVector.push_back(item);

        // Now take the first word and set it as the key because it is the email, so it is the "ID" of every line/person
        MyKey = MyVector[0];

        // Now take the rest of the vector as Value
        for (int i = 1; i < MyVector.size(); i++)
            MyValue.push_back(MyVector[i]);

        // Now add this [Key, Value] pair to the map
        MyMap[MyKey] = MyValue;
    } 

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Now hoover your mouse on this variable to see how it is structured. And do some research on how to access a map write/read etc.